# Select with Concat_ws all type from group of record

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

Using SQL, I can do something like:

```
SELECT T1.ID AS ORDER_ID, T2.CODE AS CODE  
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 AS T1 
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.O_ID
```

Output:

```
ORDER_ID    CODE 
-----------------
25005CM73   AB 
25005CM73   CD 
25005CM73   EF 
25CMMM074   CD 
25CMMM074   AB 
25CMMM074   EF 
25CMMB075   GH 
25CMMB075   IG 
25CMMB075   KL
```

I would like to return only 1 row for each `ORDER_ID` with `CONCAT`.

Expected output:

```
ORDER_ID    CODE 
--------------------
25005CM73   AB,CD,EF
25CMMM074   CD,AB,EF
25CMMB075   GH,IJ,KL
```

I don't know how to write the code for a group of ORDER_ID.

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: Try using group_concat()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT 
  ORDER_ID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CODE ORDER BY CODE SEPARATOR ',') as CODE
FROM
 (
  SELECT T1.ID AS ORDER_ID, T2.CODE AS CODE  
  FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 AS T1 
  LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.O_ID
 ) as a
GROUP BY ORDER_ID;
```

**Note:** You can directly use GROUP_CONCAT in the query while joining instead of using sub-query.